# Using LINQ GetChangeSet() to show user what happened

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

Say I have a L2S Update and I would like to display what changed to the user.  Where does GetChangeSet() get populated?  Immediately after I assign values or after `context.SubmitChanges()`?

If the second; I could, theoretically, change the return type to `IList` and then return `return context.GetChangeSet().Updates;`?

Comment: Why don't you experiment examining what `GetChangeSet()` returns after assigning values and again after calling `SubmitChanges()`.

Comment: so essentially, "this is too simple so go figure it out yourself".  I can handle that.  Will do.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it's too simple. Just that the experiment would be the first thing I'd do and I'd only post a question if that didn't clarify things or raised another issue.

Comment: @ChrisF: No worries, sometimes when I am rushed at work I will post without forethought.  If this is something that will be obvious after a little experimentation then I am cool with that.  Sometimes I just need to slow down... :)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's before you call submit changes; submit changes uses the GetChangeSet information to determine what SQL to generate etc.